# Rails simple voting gem without a voter model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, voting

I'm looking for a gem that will allow super simple voting. I'm going to let anyone vote on records, as there are no users at all. I found [this](https://github.com/medihack/make_voteable) and [this](https://rubygems.org/gems/thumbs_up) but they seem to require a 'voter' model (a user model) to act as the 'votee'.

Are there any gems out there that don't require a 'votee' model?

Answer (score 2):

If you need a simple solution why don't you just make one yourself? You can have

```
class Record < ActiveRecord ::Base
  has_many :ratings, :through => :votes
end
```

Votes would be a model that just references the record and the vote value. It could simply have `record_id` and `value` fields.

To get number of votes you could do something like `record.ratings.count`

You could also find average etc. pretty easily through a similar approach: `record.ratings.sum(:value).to_f / record.ratings.count`